# How to tell cargo to use nightly?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I know I can set rust nightly on a project by running `rustup override set nightly`. But I was wondering if I could state it on the Cargo.toml, so if I build in another machine it'll just run with nightly from the start. So far I haven't been able to find a way to do it.

Comment: STEEL's answer about the `rust-toolchain` file should help you.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup/overrides.html) it is not possible to specify it in the `Cargo.toml` file.
But you can create a new file called `rust-toolchain.toml` containing the following:

```
[toolchain]
channel = "nightly"
```

For more options look at the section [The toolchain file](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup/overrides.html#the-toolchain-file) in the same documentation.

Comment: ```In these cases the toolchain can be named in the project's directory in a file called rust-toolchain.toml or rust-toolchain. If both files are present in a directory, the latter is used for backwards compatibility.``` https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup/overrides.html#the-toolchain-file
Both `rust-toolchain.toml` and `rust-toolchain` are valid. In the documentation `rust-toolchain` get's called legacy, so the preferred file should be `rust-toolchain.toml` imho.

Comment: We have `Cargo.toml`, `.cargo/config.toml`, and now `rust-toolchain.toml`. Why must we have so many files for project configuration?